# Scroll to the top of modal window on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, modal-dialog, elementor

I'm building a site on Wordpress using Elementor page builder, and I'm having trouble sending the user back to the top of a modal when clicking 'next' on a form.

Here's the code I've been trying, and here's the page it's currently hosted: http://doortouk-co-uk.stackstaging.com/home/

*(The modal can be opened by clicking the 'Apply Now' button at the bottom of the page, section 3, 4 and 5 have the longer sections that require the scroll to top functionality)*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.e-form__buttons__wrapper__button-next').click(function(){
        jQuery(".dialog-widget-content").scrollTop(0);
        });
 })
```

Any help would be appreciated!

*Edit* - the solution was to target .dialog-lightbox-message

Comment: What's the unwanted behaviour ?

Comment: Apologies for not clarifying, at the moment nothing happens when clicking the 'next' button

Comment: Could you place a console.log() inside the callback that executes the scrollTop() to make sure that the click event is triggered and it gets called ?

Comment: Just tested on the site and it's triggering fine, it's logging 'success' to console when pressing the 'next' button on the form

Comment: Please add the css of the modal to the post, I guess it's something related to how it manages the overflow, make also sure that the selector of the modal is the right one, oit means, it must be the parent element that has the overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Took the effort to look at your website and find the issue. But for the next time, it would be great if you make a code snippet we can use to help you. Anyway, cheers and enjoy!*

I made a snippet to double check if what I was doing was correct. The thing you need would be:
`jQuery(".dialog-widget-content").animate({ scrollTop: $(".dialog-widget-content")}, 0);`

PS, run code snippet below. ;)

```js
$('.e-form__buttons__wrapper__button-next').click(function(e){
  jQuery(".dialog-widget-content").animate({ scrollTop: $(".dialog-widget-content")}, 0);
});
```

```css
.dialog-widget-content {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  overflow:auto;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dialog-widget-content">
<br/><br/>Scroll down & then click there >><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
</div>
<div class="e-form__buttons__wrapper__button-next">
click here
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, unfortunately it didn't work. I'm very much a beginner but I didn't put a snippet as I didn't think I'd be able to faithfully recreate the Wordpress / Elementor environment in a way that would allow a proper demonstration, as I know there are quirks with working with jQuery on Wordpress / Elementor sites. Sincere apologies for wasting your time!

Comment: When I look at your website and the source code, the code I gave you isn't on it? It says: `jQuery(".elementor-popup-modal .dialog-widget-content").scrollTop(0);`

Comment: Hey I changed it back as it was throwing errors, I did also try substituting $( for jQuery( to stop the errors with no luck, I've reinstated it so you can see.

Comment: Are you sure you need `.dialog-widget-content` ? Can you try `.dialog-lightbox-message`

Comment: I think it's `.elementor-popup-modal`